# What's the right mindset in using jQuery's event.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two approaches in mind on how to apply jQuery's `event.stopPropagation()`:

1. Optimistic approach - By default, all event handlers are ***without*** `stopPropagation()`. `stopPropagation()` would be added to a handler only if there's some unnecessary and undesired behaviour caused by event bubbling.
2. Pessimistic approach - By default, `stopPropagation()` is added to all event handlers. If there's some desired behaviour missing due to disconnected even bubbling, then the corresponding `stopPropagation()` would get removed.

I was wondering which one of the two, or neither, is the mindset I should have when utilizing `stopPropagation()` in my development. I am leaning more towards 2) because it looks like it would have better performance because unnecessary bubbling gets prevented. I would like to hear from experts on the topic.

Comment: Calling `stopPropagation` just changes the Event Object so the ancestor elements ignore it, but the Event still actually bubbles up the DOM and creates overhead.

Comment: @Jasper - Didn't know about this! Then the better performance I had in mind would never get realized. Thx for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `stopPropagation` everywhere isn't good. It breaks event delegation*, is probably less efficient unless you literally add handlers to every single element on the page (and if you're doing that, you should be using event delegation), and you might not remember to do it.

So rule of thumb: Only call `stopPropagation` when you need to do so.

---

* That is, `.live`, `.delegate`, and the delegate version of `.on`.

---

Here's an example of event delegation, which relies on bubbling to listen for events that originate from elements added *after* the listener was created:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'a') {
        console.log('A link was clicked!');
    }
});
```

Here's somebody throwing in jQuery that breaks that:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any `<a>` that is a descendant of a `<div>` will no longer get its clicks handled! Please don't do this.

Comment: Binding via event delegation is faster (more so when talking about more elements) but the time it takes for an event handler to fire increases. Wouldn't that suggest that binding directly to an element will react to interactions faster? Although I generally agree with your answer, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Jasper: That's not really the point - you still absolutely need event delegation for, say, handling events on elements added after the listener was created. See update.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. Although I think people too quickly turn to delegation, for instance when adding new element via an AJAX request you can just bind to the element(s) before adding them to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Call `stopPropagation` only if you realy need it. And remember, if you use jQuery `live` function and you stop it, live handler never calls, because `live` event stored in `document` element.

Comment: Slight correction, `.live()` binds to the `document` element. `.live()` the same as `$(document).delegate(SELECTOR, EVENT, EVENT-HANDLER)`.